# Como pegar o retorno Task<int> de uma função (MediaTR) - Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, task

Como faço para pegar o valor inteiro retornado através de uma Task? Já tentei fazer de várias maneiras, conforme vi em fóruns na net, mas não consegui. Tentei usar var customerId = Bus.SendCommand(registerCommand).Result, mas não funciona...
Obrigado a todos :)

```
public class CustomerCommandHandler : CommandHandler,
    IRequestHandler<RegisterNewCustomerCommand, int>,       
{
    private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;
    private readonly IMediatorHandler Bus;

    public CustomerCommandHandler(ICustomerRepository customerRepository, 
                                  IUnitOfWork uow,
                                  IMediatorHandler bus,
                                  INotificationHandler<DomainNotification> notifications) :base(uow, bus, notifications)
    {
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
        Bus = bus;
    }

    public Task<int> Handle(RegisterNewCustomerCommand message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!message.IsValid())
        {
            NotifyValidationErrors(message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        var customer = new Customer(Guid.NewGuid(), message.Name, message.Email, message.BirthDate);

        if (_customerRepository.GetByEmail(customer.Email) != null)
        {
            Bus.RaiseEvent(new DomainNotification(message.MessageType, "The customer e-mail has already been taken."));
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        _customerRepository.Add(customer);

        if (Commit())
        {
            Bus.RaiseEvent(new CustomerRegisteredEvent(customer.Id, customer.Name, customer.Email, customer.BirthDate));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(customer.Id);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _customerRepository.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Chamada:

```
 public void Register(CustomerViewModel customerViewModel)
{
    var registerCommand = _mapper.Map<RegisterNewCustomerCommand>(customerViewModel);
    var customerId = Bus.SendCommand(registerCommand); /////????????????????????
}
```

Comment: `SendCommand` é `async`?

Comment: Não é async @Barbetta. :)

Comment: Nesse caso seria bom vermos o erro que dá, sempre usei `.Result`

Comment: O Problema é que dá erro de compilação se eu usar o .Result (Bus.SendCommand(registerCommand).Result;). É como se ele não existisse... Tem referenciar algo? Atualizei o post com a classe completa.

Comment: Estranho, e qual a mensagem de erro exibida?  Ao referenciar o `System.Threading.Tasks` para usar o Task<T> já deveria ser suficiente

Comment: Dessa forma aparece um erro dizendo que não é possível converter TASK em Inteiro: var registerCommand = _mapper.Map<RegisterNewCustomerCommand>(customerViewModel);
            var retorno = Task.FromResult(Bus.SendCommand(registerCommand)).Result;

            int customerId = retorno;

Comment: Agora, estou conseguindo receber, mas não consigo jogar o valor de Result para uma variável...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99010/discussion-between-barbetta-and-master-jr).

Comment: O seu SendCommand provavelmente retorna uma Task, então fazer a conversão implícita não funcionaria. Como ele retorna uma task, basta adicionar .Result no final, se mesmo assim não funcionou, poste a sua classe concreta do IMediatorHandler, é possível que a implementação do SendCommand esteja incorreta. Segue um projeto de exemplo, faça uma comparação https://github.com/superrfm/MediaTrAspNetCore

Comment: Assim está:  public interface IMediatorHandler
    {
        Task SendCommand<T>(T command) where T : Command;
        Task RaiseEvent<T>(T @event) where T : Event;
    }